# Loading Shapefiles into PostGIS using shapefile import/export manager

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0, postgis-1.5, boundless-suite

I am a complete beginner with PostGIS. I've started learning it using the tutorials provided by Boundless. In section 4 of this tutorial where I want to import shapefile in PostGIS, I do not have the PostGIS shapefile Import/Export Manager tool in the PgAdmin III.

I've followed the tutorial step by step. They have never pointed if I need to install such tool or how to activate it, etc. Any idea what the problem could be? and how I can solve this?

I've installed Postgresql 9.3, PostGIS 2.1 , pgAdmin3 1.12.3 on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.

by the way, the relevant page for this issue in the tutorial is at:
http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/loading_data.html

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to GIS StackExchange. Please provide version of postgresql and postgis you installed and OS.

Comment: Thanks. the information you asked has been updated in the main question.

Comment: Look in C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/shp2pgsql.exe if you can find it

Comment: Yes. I executed it as admin, a separate window popped and closed immediately. Then I checked the plugin menu in pgAdmin III, nothing changed...

Comment: I do get a warning when I connect to Postgresql using PgAdmin3, which says:
"This version of pgAdmin has only been tested with Postgresql version 9.0 and may not function correctly with this server. Please upgrade pgAdmin"
Could this be the problem?

Comment: Definately, try to upgrade you pgadmin3 but I am not sure upgraded version are available for Winodows Server 2012.

Comment: @Catlover While the version of pgAdmin that you have is strange (my fresh install has 1.18), I don't have the plugin in pgAdmin nor is it enabled from the opengeo dashboard.  Just confirming that it is not enabled as part of the default Windows install.

Comment: It should be default install with PostGIS and pgAdmin 1.18

Comment: I had pgAdmin 1.18 first. When I faced this problem I googled and found someone with the same problem who used pgAdmin 1.12 and the problem was solved for him. That's why I changed the pgAdmin version to see if it works for me, which did not!

Comment: @Scro So where do you have thin plugin?!

Comment: try to re-install postgis over your upgraded pgadmin

Comment: i had the same problem and solved with your guidance thank you so much Sorin Calinica.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for PostGIS 2.0 Shapefile and DBF Loader Exporter, so access "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\postgisgui\shp2pgsql-gui.exe"

Comment: I can't find it in the specified folder... Do I need to re-install PostGIS?

Comment: Yes, definitely!

Comment: Can't I perhaps search and download only this package, instead of re-installing PostGIS? Will it work in that way?

Comment: Just try and see. It may be possible.

Comment: Download a bundle from here http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/windows/pg93/ , unzip it and copy the postgisgui folder according to the link I gave you.

Comment: In OpenGeo suite install, it is here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Boundless\OpenGeo\pgsql\bin

Comment: Thank you Sorin, and also others. Problem solved! Cheers...